# Custom CheckedTextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-view

I need to create custom CheckedText view in android like below image

[image]

As I am new to android, please, can any one help me, how to achieve this.

Comment: The "tick" is purely unnecessary, UX wise.

Comment: You can create class which extends LinearLayout and then set background of the shape you created and inflate CheckedTextView.

Comment: onClick change background of your text and save them in a list.